# Adding Azure webrole instances does not affect MVC4 webservice throughput

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-roles

I have a very simple MVC4 post action as part of Azure webrole:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Request request)
    {
        return new JsonResult() 
        { 
            Data = "OK", 
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet 
        };
    }
```

1. I deployed the webrole to Azure.
2. I used benchmark (ab.exe) and see that 25 concurrent requests are processed no longer then 1 sec for instance.
3. Now I want to scale out by adding a new webrole instance so I'm expecting +25 concurrent users will be also happy with 1 sec delay.
4. I ran becnhmark one more time and the result was the same as for 1 webrole instance.

P.S I have Free Azure Subscription. Webroles have Small VM size.

Why when I am adding new webrole instances webservice capacity is not increased? Have I missed some configuration or what?

Answer (score 3):

What do you expect to change for 25 concurrent users?

The idea of scaling out with more instances is to handle more concurrent users, not to process the small amount of users faster ...

I suggest you to test edge case - say `1000` concurrent users, find the point of saturation with a single instance. Assuming single instance can safely handle `546` concurrent users. Now increase the number of instances, warm up the test with `100` concurrent users. Increase to `1000` concurrent users. Does your service now handle `1000` concurrent users fine, instead of just `546` ... This is the idea of adding more instances ...

All imaginary numbers.

**UPDATE**

Interesting, you say you use:

> ab -n 25 -c 25 -p json.file -T "application/json; charset=utf-8"
>   xxxxx.cloudapp.net

Now from documentation:

> -c concurrency Number of multiple requests to perform at a time. Default is one request at a time.
>
> -n requests Number of requests to perform for the benchmarking session. The default is to just perform a single request which usually
>   leads to non-representative benchmarking results.

What do you expect to be the result when you only conduct 25 concurent requests? I suggest that you use the following parameters:

> ab -n 150 -c 1000 -p json.file -T "application/json; charset=utf-8"
>   xxxxx.cloudapp.net

And check the results again!

Comment: That's exactly what I did. My point of saturation is 25 in opposite to your 546 for 1 web instance.

Comment: One more time. I have MVC4 webservice which "does nothing". I want any of potential users do not wait longer than 1 sec for a response. So I would like to identify how many concurrent users can interract with the webservice and do not wait more than 1 sec. I found that it is 25 concurrent users. Then I added 1 more webrole instance. Now I am expecting 50 concurrent users can interrcact with the webservice and any of them will not wait longer than 1 sec. But it's not - 50 concurrent users will wait for their responses 2 sec! So adding 1 more instance had no effect. I am wondering why?

Comment: do you have adequate warm up for the test?

Comment: Yes, I have. I made even 10 instances and there is no effect. Is it configuration or limits of Free Subscription? However it allowed me to add 10 instances and I see they are running well in the Azure Management Portal.

Comment: Interesting observation. I have to test it on my own to see it. Can you provide the exact ab.exe command line you are using?

Comment: ab -n 25 -c 25 -p json.file -T "application/json; charset=utf-8" http://xxxxx.cloudapp.net/